# iads not showing up after weeks of being on the app store

Tags: ios, iad

My game has been live on the app store for over a month.

The test iads show up when testing a sandbox version, and in the iad portion of iTunes Connect, it is clear that requests are being made by my game.

No live ad has ever shown up in my game.

The fill rate is 0%.

I've tried contacting apple for help, but they have been unresponsive.

What more can I do?

Comment: Essentially, you need to wait for Apple to respond to you. I've had similar issues with ads not being filled on the release of a new app and submitting an update corrected these issues. On a side note, the fill rate for many of my apps have fallen drastically in recent days. Apple's inventory of ads may just be low at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been waiting on Apple for just under a month as well, and came across this while looking for an answer. Apple has been somewhat responsive to me, but their answers seem fairly automated.

I have received this message:

"Hello,

Thanks for your follow-up.  Our technical teams continue to work on this issue and we will contact you as soon as an update is available.  In the meantime, please let us know if you make any additional changes to your app so that we can make a note of this.

We appreciate your continued patience and understanding."

more than once, and they never "contact me as soon as an update is available.

I'm considering incorporating Admob into my apps as well, and when

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

gets called, have it switch to Admob.